# Not able to install Plone 5.0.8 on MacOS High Sierra (10.13.3)

Tags: macos, ssl, openssl, plone, plone-5.x

I'm a new user of Plone (or trying to be), to build my own Website.

I'm trying to install Plone 5.0.8 on MacOS 10.13.3, using the Python 2.7 that come along with the OS. 
Using Plone-5.0.8-UnifiedInstaller-r1. Already had XCode. Updated and downloaded Command Line Tools for Xcode 9.2 MacOS 10.13.

Tried "./install.sh" in Terminal from installer folder and got:

```
Continue with the command line:

install.sh standalone \
--target="/Users/felipelukavei/Plone"  

1) Yes
2) No
#? 1

./preflight: line 1707: config.log: Permission denied
./preflight: line 1717: config.log: Permission denied

Unable to run preflight check. Basic build tools are missing.
You may get more information about what went wrong by running
sh ./preflight
Aborting installation.
```

then I'd run "sudo sh ./preflight" and got something similar to the following, but now I have installed some of the requirements using homebrew.

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for bunzip2... yes
checking for tar... yes
checking for gunzip... yes
checking for make... yes
checking for patch... yes
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking for xslt-config... /usr/bin/xslt-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for main in -lreadline... yes
checking readline/readline.h usability... yes
checking readline/readline.h presence... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for gzread in -lz... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for jpeg_read_header in -ljpeg... yes
checking jpeglib.h usability... yes
checking jpeglib.h presence... yes
checking for jpeglib.h... yes
checking for SSL_accept in -lssl... yes
checking ssl.h usability... no
checking ssl.h presence... no
checking for ssl.h... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... (cached) yes
preflight: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating buildenv.sh
```

I have installed OpenSSL, and made like everything that was listed on the 5 first pages on Google for tags like ssl, headers, mac os, Plone, OpenSSL. After that, I realized that OpenSSL install has no impact on the outcoming since even uninstalled the OpenSSL check is Ok (looks like High Sierra already have it), but ssl.h I never got.

I still have in my terminal back commands:

```
ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
env LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

The result from "find /usr -iname "ssl.h*"" is:

```
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2n/include/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/local/share/doc/openssl/html/man7/ssl.html
```

The result from "which openssl" is:

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

Linking openssl no longer works and looks like my problem is not related to OpenSSL package itself, but with something I have no idea.

Using sudo ./install.sh gives me different output, but since Plone documentation [[link]](https://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html#install-requirements) says "The resulting installation is self-contained, does not touch system files, and is safe to play with (no root/sudoing is needed)", thought I should not force it. Looks like sudo get me root install and the output follows:

```
Testing /usr/bin/python2.7 for Zope/Plone requirements....
/usr/bin/python2.7 looks OK. We will use it.


Root install method chosen. Will install for use by users:
  ZEO & Client Daemons:      plone_daemon
  Code Resources & buildout: plone_buildout


Detailed installation log being written to /Users/felipelukavei/Downloads/Plone-5.0.8-UnifiedInstaller-r1/install.log
Installing Plone 5.0.8 at /Applications/Plone

We do not know how to add users and groups in this environment. This is no problem if the required users and group already exist.
id: plone_daemon: no such user
id for plone_daemon returned
id: plone_daemon: no such user
Expected to find uid for plone_daemon and gid for plone_group but did not.
Please use your system tools to create/edit required users and group, then try again.
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi - I will post a link to your question in our forum https://community.plone.org which is the best place to get technical support. **update: here is the post: https://community.plone.org/t/not-able-to-install-plone-5-0-8-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3/5972 **

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope I get some help (:

Comment: You have one response in the forum so far. Please go there and answer questions rather than wait here!

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered on Plone Community: https://community.plone.org/t/not-able-to-install-plone-5-0-8-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3/5972/29

Thanks!